# UIKeyboardDidShowNotification selector called twice if UITextField has inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I have an `UIView` that has several `UITextField`s inside. I have registered selector for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. When I touch the field, the selector gets called and the keyboard is shown. If i than tap to next field selector is not called, which is what should happen.

Now if i do everything again, but attach simple `inputAccessoryView` to field, something different happens. Whenever I touch the field selector is called, although keyboard is already shown.

Is this a bug by apple, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Been hitting a similar problem, seems that it is "normal" the extra notification is because of the "inputView" (as you already inferred). The first notification contains the **original size of the keyboard** while the second contains the **size of the keyboard plus the size of the input view** in the UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey part of the notification. My guess is that as the size of what it considers a keyboard "changes" delivers a new notification saying "hey the size has changed". Weird? yes, but it is the expected behaviour as far as I can tell.

So if you want to react to only one you have to filter by that frame value...

See: dgangsta answer here: (confirms my guess)
[can't get correct value of keyboard height in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874975/cant-get-correct-value-of-keyboard-height-in-ios8)