# Keyboard autocorrection height (with/without the autocorrection)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

I get the keyboard height like this:

```
- (void)keyboardNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
}
```

Now, I have the keyboard height.
But without the autocorrection height:

[image]

If the `UITextAutocorrectionType` is `YES` / `NO` the keyboard height stay the same.

How can I get the Keyboard autocorrection height?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't get correct value of keyboard height in iOS8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874975/cant-get-correct-value-of-keyboard-height-in-ios8)

Comment: Have you tried converting the rect to the view coordinates? Like `keyboardFrameBeginRect =  [myView convertRect: keyboardFrameBeginRect fromView:nil];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
 CGRect keyboardBounds;
        [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
   // Need to translate the bounds to account for rotation.
  keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];
```

Comment: here keyboardBounds = whole keyboard frame including UITextAutocorrection part.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`. This will be called every time when suggestion bar shows or hides.

```
NSConcreteNotification 0xc472900 {name = UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification; userInfo = {
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 216}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 588}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 372}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 480}, {320, 216}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction = 0;
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 264}, {320, 216}}";
}}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but how does this help me? Maybe I miss something, I asked about the keybord height + autocorrction height, In your answer I see the problem :/ the keyboard height only (without autocorrection height)

Comment: If autocorrection bar is there, It will return that height also.

Comment: @NiravGadhiya it doesn't work that way, or I don't get how to find autocorrection height