# Keyboard text autocorrection height in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to know the keyboard size including autocorrection part.

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
   // ...
}
```

`keyboardSize` variable is the keyboard size, but autocorrection part is not added to it.

I checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/30433821/4468859 but it did not work in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Handling keyboard is very painful. You can use https://github.com/evgenyneu/UnderKeyboard