# keyboardWillShow shows a strange height the first time

Tags: ios, swift

When using a custom keyboard, `keyboardWillShow` is ran twice (normal behavior) the first the height is 0 but the second is the correct height in my case 667. The problem is that this is only true the second time the viewController is showed. The first time I get the strange output below.

**Console the first time the view controller is opened:**

> keyboardSize  CGRect  (origin = (x = 0, y = 258), size = (width = 0, height = 2.8876618518302306E-314))

**Console the second time the view controller is opened:**

> keyboardSize  CGRect  (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 667))

**My code:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                if keyboardSize.height > 0 { //in case of custom keyborad
                    kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
                    self.animateTextField(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried: `userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]`? Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874975/cant-get-correct-value-of-keyboard-height-in-ios8

Comment: Thanks this does solve the problem but I really want to understand the behavior.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation suggesting why the two heights would be different. It is probably just some bug. The `y` coordinate looks to be incorrect as well and is probably related to the same bug.

Answer (score 13):

Change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. Thats all:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
    if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
      if keyboardSize.height > 0 { //in case of custom keyborad
        kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
        self.animateTextField(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Keep coding.............. :)

Comment: Thank you....wasted so much time on UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey myself today.