# How to reliably get keyboard height in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events, uikeyboard, notificationcenter

I have this code to detect when keyboard is shown and get its height.

```
@objc func keyboardWasShown (_ notification: Notification) {
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size;
    print ("KEYBOARD SIZE: \(keyboardSize.height)");
}
```

At first, when I first time tap on a UITextView to make it first responder, the console showed 271.0 point.

Then I tap on the view to dismiss the keyboard. And then I tap again on the UITextView. Now it's showing 226.0 point.

There's no change to the keyboard layout on the first and subsequent trial. At first I always get 271, and then the next are always 226. The correct one is 271.

Why is this happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: @Scriptable yes, I have mentioned this in the answer I post by myself below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

don't know your exact scenario but try to use IQKeyboard it will deal with all your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: your most welcome!

Comment: Please give definitive answers, no suggestions or recommendations. This answer should probably be in the comments.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh this actually solves all my current and future problems with iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

From is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25886712/3003927), I found that I'm supposed to use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`.

Comment: This should be the right answer, not the recommendations of IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 4):

you can get frame of keyboard by

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardDidShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    center.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}



func keyBoardDidShow(_ notification:Notification)
{
    print((notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"] as! CGRect).height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import [this](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library into your project. It will handle each and everything automatically.